# String as a parameter in a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, string, parameters, constructor

```
class example {
private:
    char Name[100];

public:
    example() { strcpy(Name, "no_name_yet"); }
    example(char n[100]) { strcpy(Name, n); }
};

int main() {
    example ex;
    char n[100];

    cout<<"Give name ";
    cin>>n;
    example();
}
```

I want to use the constructor with the parameter so that when the user gives a name it gets copied to the name variable. How can I use the constructor with the parameter instead of the default one?
I tried

```
example(n)
example(char n)
example(*n)
example(n[100])
```

but none of them work.

Comment: It should be pointed out to you, that as a parameter, `char n[100]` is identical to `char n[99]`, `char n[]` and `char * n`.  That is to say, the actual parameter type is pointer to char, and the number is ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Easy:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class example {
 private:
    std::string name;

 public:
    example() : name("no name yet"){}
    example(std::string const& n) : name(n){}
};


int main() {
     example ex;
     std::string n;

     std::cout << "Give name ";
     std::cin >> n;
     example ex(n); // you have to give your instance a name, "ex" here
                    // and actually pass the contructor parameter
}
```

Comment: As a general rule (at least in C++03), if you are going to copy the argument anyway, pass it by value.

Comment: @Björn: I might aswell do that and use `std::move` in the ctor, but y'know, I might also just keep it simple. :)

Comment: @System: What exactly do you mean with that? You are only invoking the copy ctor of `std::string` here, which is unavoidable.

Comment: i meant without the std::string, with the strcopy()

Comment: Why do you want to use char[100] and risk buffer overflow and make your life hard?

Comment: @david if I use std::string can I set the size of the string?

Comment: @System: `strcopy` *is* a kind of copy contructor, for C style raw strings. It's also internally used by `std::string`. Also, `std::string` grows automatically.

Comment: `std::string` is dynamically sized to fit its contents. Life is painful without it.

Comment: @david when using std::string we can access the memory with a pointer? is the data stored in consecutive memory shells?

Comment: @System: It's best if you get a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), because those are basic questions about `std::string`. In general, the memory is consecutive. In the new standard (C++11), it's even promised.

Comment: The string is stored in a contiguous block of memory. Why do you want to poke at it with pointers?

Comment: @xeo I have Stroustrup's book but maybe it wasn't a very good choice for a beginner.. I am still at the beginning of it though..

Comment: @System: Bjarne's book is a reference material rather than a teaching material.

Comment: @David: `std::string::c_str()`, for C interfacing.

Answer (score 2):

It is `example my_instance_of_example(n)`.

I must note, however, that using char arrays for strings is not what you do in C++. You should use `std::string` instead, it gives you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: if i do example ex(n) it says that example ex was previously declared

Comment: That's because you already declared (and constructed it) right at the beginning of main. You need to declare it once only.

Comment: this worked but what if I wanted to use the ex object somewhere before in main so I needed to declare it at the beginning?

Comment: @System If you need to use that variable before, then you should use an assignment instead of a constructor.